# Another NHibernate Mapping Mystery! Getting count in hbm file

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hbm

I am trying to retrieve the count of items allocated to a container in my hbm file. I've done a bit of digging and managed to get my hbm code this far (below!). I want the count to be retrieved every time a container object is queried. I could use an interceptor but I assume there's a better way. Am I on the right track or should I use a different strategy to get the count loaded up?

Thanks.

P.S. We're using NH v2.2

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-lazy="false" assembly="MyEntities" namespace="Entities.Containers">   <class name="Container" table="[Container]" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <id name="Id" column="Id" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Capacity" column="Capacity">
      <column name="Capacity" />
    </property>
    <property name="Description" column="Description" length="50" type="String">
      <column name="Description" />
    </property>
    <loader query-ref="sqCurrentContainerAllocation"/>   </class>

  <sql-query name="sqCurrentContainerAllocation">
    <return-scalar column="AllocatedItemsCount" type="int"></return-scalar>
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [ContainerTracking]
      WHERE [ContainerId] = :Id   </sql-query> 
   </hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: I will do some profiling to see what gets executed by NH. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get some calculated property, you can use mapping with `formula`.
Let's extend your C# class:

```
public class Container
{
  ... // ID, Capacity, Description
  public virtual int MyCount { get; set; }
```

And extend your mapping

```
<class name="Container" table="[Container]"
  ...
  <property name="MyCount" insert="false" update="false" >
      <formula>
      (
         SELECT count(*) 
         FROM [ContainerTracking] as ct
         WHERE ct.[ContainerId] = Id
      )
      </formula>
  </property>
```

the `Id` will be replaced with somethink like '_this.Id', the name of the column Id and its alias

This will of course load the count all the time (except projections) so think twice before use it